# Qml RightToLeft Alignment placeholderText

Tags: qml

Greetings Dear Programmers ;))
Im Recently entered the world of Qt programming , I want Text PlaceHolder Align From right to left'm grateful for help Me [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2Tb9.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you need to know about Right to Left interfaces is explained in [QML Right-to-left User Interfaces](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-righttoleft.html).

You need at least the following properties in your `Text` type:

```
horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
width: parent.width // whatever you want here, but 'width' must be present.
```

A quick example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow

    width: 400
    height: 300

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1

        anchors.fill: parent        
        color: "lightsteelblue"        

        Rectangle {
            height : 20
            width : parent.width / 2
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            color : "white"

            Text {
                text: "هذا هو مجرد اختبار"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
                width: parent.width
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Right to left text QML interface example]